# Nginx cannot open files but files exist

Tags: symfony, docker, nginx

I'm working on a symfony 4 application. Website works with a let's encrypt certificate in a docker container.

I have an issue with assets links :

```
<script src="/build/js/app.js"></script>
```

Link is good, but I have this issue :

[nginx issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtRN3.png)

App.js path :

[app.js path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jn3vE.png)

My nginx configuration :

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name esgi.be;

    location ^~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
        root  /var/www/symfony/;
    }
}

server {
    listen      443           ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443           ssl http2;
    server_name               esgi.be;

    ssl                       on;
    ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/esgi.be/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/esgi.be/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate   /etc/letsencrypt/live/esgi.be/chain.pem;

    access_log                /dev/stdout;
    error_log                 /dev/stderr info;

    root /var/www/symfony/public;

    location ^~ /build/ {
        alias /var/www/symfony/public/build/;
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        internal;
    }

}
```

What can I do to fix that ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Most likely a permissions error... Try `ls -al /var/www/symfony/public/build/js` and check who is owning the file (user and group). Is it owner by nginx user?

Comment: recently in SO another person had almost the same issue, finally he fixed it by adding in his docker image `WORKDIR /var/www/symfony/` . Also i noticy that in your nginx configuration the root path is `/var/www/symfony/` and not `/var/www/symfony/public` here is the official nginx configuration that symfony provides https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx

Comment: I bet for a permission error, I am sure you are building the asset as root user ;-)

Comment: @ThomasDecaux l i've used this command :

    chown -R www-data.www-data public/

but errors are still here :(

Comment: @Preciel same thing :/

Comment: @knetsi i've put `WORKDIR /var/www/symfony/` in my Dockerfile but it doesn't change anything.
Also, i've already put `root /var/www/symfony/public;` in the ssl server section.

Comment: it's `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/symfony/`. `www-data.www-data` most likely didn't works... Or did you simply misstype?

Comment: Try removing the Nginx location build block (maybe the alias is wrong).

Comment: I just now get http://esgi.be/build/js/app.js and received js content. Seems like it's ok.

Comment: This project is a study project, and the deadline is very close. So I rollback to http.. I’ll fix this issue when I have time. 
Thank you all! :)